Resolve modules relative to package folder when using jest.doMock and not from a jest preset package
I have a monorepo, backed by Rush, and there's a jest preset package that is used by many other packages. I would like to include in this preset a javascript file that will be part of the setupFiles jest config. This javascript file will have content like this:
import {mockedFuncA} from '<internalPackageA>'

jest.doMock('<internalPackage>', () => ({
  funcA: mockedFuncA
}))

The issue is that jest.doMock will resolve modules relative to the preset package and not from the package that is using the preset. I could reduce a lot of duplicated configuration files if I was able to get jest to resolve mocked packages relative to the rootDir, when using files from a preset.
And I can't make  a dependency of the preset package because it would create a circular dependency.
Thanks
